# ansible fatal: "sudo: a password is required", even after priveleges are escalated

Tags: ansible

while trying to setup a remote machine using ansible, I am running into the following issue:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

I am already escalating privileges in the playbook using the following method:

```
  become: yes
  become_method: community.general.sudosu
```

two of the tasks are successfully being executed with escalated privileges as well.
i am running into this error when I run the following task:

```
    - name: Pushing Nebula configs to node
      synchronize: 
        src: <local dir>
        dest: "/etc/<target_dir>/"
        dest_port: "{{ ssh_port }}"
        mode: push
      delegate_to: localhost
```

the  user I am using does not require a sudo password.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, please

```yaml
- name: Pushing Nebula configs to node
  synchronize: 
    src: <local dir>
    dest: "/etc/<target_dir>/"
    dest_port: "{{ ssh_port }}"
    mode: push
  delegate_to: localhost
  vars:
    ansible_become: false
```